# How do I get sub-numbering for theorems (Theorem 1.A., Theorem 1.B., Theorem 2.)?

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am trying to number my theorems as follows:

**Theorem 1.A.** First part of a theorem.

**Theorem 1.B.** Second part of the theorem.

**Theorem 2.** A theorem with no parts.

The following almost works:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theorempart}{Theorem}[theorem]
```

But it does not increment the theorem counter as I want, so that

```
\begin{theorempart}First part of a theorem.
\end{theorempart}

\begin{theorempart}Second part of the theorem.
\end{theorempart}

\begin{theorem}A theorem with no parts.
\end{theorem}
```

gives:

**Theorem 0.1.** First part of a theorem.

**Theorem 0.2.** Second part of the theorem.

**Theorem 1.** A theorem with no parts.

Also, I don't know how to get the part-number to be a letter instead of a number.

I am using MiKTeX.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/230569/35864 for an extension of the accepted answer that works with `hyperref`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The model I used is that of the `subequations` environment in `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subtheorem}[1]{%
  \def\subtheoremcounter{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\theparentnumber{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \setcounter{parentnumber}{\value{#1}}%
  \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{\theparentnumber.\Alph{#1}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{\subtheoremcounter}{\value{parentnumber}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{parentnumber}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:one}
One
\end{thm}

\begin{subtheorem}{thm}\label{thm:two}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:twoA}
Two, first part
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:twoB}
Two, second part
\end{thm}
\end{subtheorem}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:three}
Three
\end{thm}

\ref{thm:one}, \ref{thm:two}, \ref{thm:twoA}, \ref{thm:twoB}, \ref{thm:three}.

\end{document}
```

You enclose the part in which the theorems have to be "subnumbered" in the `subtheorem` environment, which takes as argument the name of the theorem-like environment you want to affect.

The `\label` commands are not mandatory, but you can see that you can also set a "global" label for the subnumbered theorem.

Comment: @egreg This is great, but somehow the hyperlinks generated with \cref{} no longer work. I generated Theorems 5.A and 5.B like this, but any link to 5.A jumps to Theorem 1 and any link to 5.B jumps to Theorem 2. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @ItsmeMimi This warrants a new question.

Comment: @egreg Done: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276238/cleveref-interaction-with-theorem-subnumbering. Thanks for the code though, this already helped me a lot!

Comment: While this is great (and I've already given it a +1 from a past visit), I feel this issue with the false anchors should be made clearer. I had put this code into my preamble, not having really read the comments. I was then having this issue, and coming back to this question saw that I wasn't the first. It's perhaps worth noting at the top of the answer that the referencing doesn't work as some would like, but that it was fixed (with only a very minor change) in the question linked by @ItsmeMini. As always egreg, thanks for the extremely useful code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of fixing this easily is by the below code. However, one need to reset the `subtheorem` counter after each new `theorem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{subtheorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thesubtheorem}{\thetheorem.\Alph{subtheorem}}
\setcounter{theorem}{1}

\begin{document}
   
\begin{subtheorem}First part of a theorem.
\end{subtheorem}

\begin{subtheorem}Second part of the theorem.
\end{subtheorem}

\begin{theorem}A theorem with no parts.
\end{theorem}

\setcounter{subtheorem}{0}
\begin{subtheorem}Second part of the theorem.
\end{subtheorem}

\end{document}
```

This gives:
**Theorem 1.A.** First part of a theorem.
**Theorem 1.B.** Second part of the theorem.
**Theorem 2.** A theorem with no parts.
**Theorem 2.A.** Second part of the theorem.