# Creating arabic and alpha theorem numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems

For my Thesis I am stating a number of Theorems (Working Propositions actually). Using the theorem environment I do get some thing like:

WP1 *My first WP*

I create this by using

```
\begin{WP}  
 my first WP
\end{WP}
```

I have defined the WP environment with

```
\newtheorem{WP}{Working Proposition}
```

However if I add a second (and a third etc) the numbering continues 1 , 2 ,3 etc

Occasionally I would like to be able to creat a WP2a and WP2b and then continue with 3.

When and where I extend to the a,b,c etc is random.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43346/how-do-i-get-sub-numbering-for-theorems-theorem-1-a-theorem-1-b-theorem-2 help?

Comment: @egreg Ah, I like your solution in that other question. I think I'll delete my answer to this one.

Comment: Damn I had not found that question, I thought i searched thorough through here 
But if it only were that easy....