# restatable non-nested sub-theorems

Tags: numbering, nesting, thmtools

I want to create restatable sub-theorems without nesting them. I am using packages `thmtools` and `thm-restate`.

By non-nested sub-theorems, I mean a similar structure to what we use for sections and subsections: A section does not enclose its paragraphs and subsections, yet these are conceptually all children of a section.
In my MWE, I want to create a restatable theorem (no. 1) followed by a regular paragraph of text.
Then, I want add a number of sub-theorems (numbered 1.x), each followed by a bit of text.

AFAIK [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43351/31877) does not work with restatables, and the [thmtools docs](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/exptl/thmtools/thmtools.pdf) don't mention anything like this either.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}

\newtheorem{goal}{Learning Goal}

\begin{document}
\section{Numbers}
We want to learn about numbers.

\subsection{Small Numbers}
Let's start with small numbers.
\begin{restatable}{goal}{gI}
    Count to 3.
\end{restatable}
Counting to 3 is the most essential skill in the `small number department'.
We will master this skill in a number of steps which are described below.

%This should be sub-goal 1.1
\begin{restatable}{goal}{gI_i}
    The number 1.
\end{restatable}
We will ask Elmo to tell us about the number 1.

%This should be sub-goal 1.2
\begin{restatable}{goal}{gI_ii}
    The number 2.
\end{restatable}
This one will be taken care of by Cookie Monster.

%This should be sub-goal 1.3
\begin{restatable}{goal}{gI_iii}
    The number 3.
\end{restatable}
This is the toughest one so far.
We will have to rely on the Count to explain all about this number.

\section{Letters}
\ldots
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work? It just uses the facilities provided by `thmtools`, which seems to be identical with `thm-restate`. (I'm not sure about this but the addition of the latter didn't seem necessary for your example.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheorem[name=Learning Goal]{goal}
\declaretheorem[
  name=Learning Goal,
  parent=goal]
  {subgoal}

\begin{document}
\section{Numbers}
We want to learn about numbers.

\subsection{Small Numbers}
Let's start with small numbers.
\begin{restatable}{goal}{gI}
    Count to 3.
\end{restatable}
Counting to 3 is the most essential skill in the `small number department'.
We will master this skill in a number of steps which are described below.

%This should be sub-goal 1.1
\begin{restatable}{subgoal}{gI_i}
    The number 1.
\end{restatable}
We will ask Elmo to tell us about the number 1.

%This should be sub-goal 1.2
\begin{restatable}{subgoal}{gI_ii}
    The number 2.
\end{restatable}
This one will be taken care of by Cookie Monster.

%This should be sub-goal 1.3
\begin{restatable}{subgoal}{gI_iii}
    The number 3.
\end{restatable}
This is the toughest one so far.
We will have to rely on the Count to explain all about this number.


\section{Letters}
\ldots
\end{document}
```

[image: Goals and Sub-Goals]