# Number/Letter Theorem

Tags: numbering, theorems

Is there any way from the code below that a number letter/number theorem can be generated? I am trying to achieve a theorem labeled 1.1A.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

 \newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]
 \newcounter{tmp}

 \begin{document}

 \chapter{Test Chapter}
 \begin{theo}
 test
 \end{theo}

 \begingroup
 \setcounter{tmp}{\value{theo}}% store current value of theorem counter
 \setcounter{theo}{0} %assign desired value to theorem counter
  \renewcommand\thetheo{\Alph{theo}}% locally redefine the representation of    the theorem counter
 \begin{theo}
 test
 \end{theo}
  \endgroup


 \end{document}
```

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43346/how-do-i-get-sub-numbering-for-theorems-theorem-1-a-theorem-1-b-theorem-2 help?

Comment: Is the inner `theo` a `sub` theorem then? What should `1.1a` indicate. Subtheorem `a` of theorem 1.1? I don't think the group is really necessary

Comment: I'm afraid your write-up isn't very clear. Currently, your code generates two theorem-like environments, labelled "Theorem 1.1" and "Theorem A". Please be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: apologies.. i am trying to achieve a theorem labeled 1.1A

Comment: And what does the "A" in "1.1A" stand for? Does Theorem 1.1A represent an entirely separate theorem, or is it a sub-theorem of Theorem 1.1? Please advise.

Comment: @coder123: If you're wanting to provide a slight variation of `Theorem 1.1`, you could use `Theorem 1.1'`. Could you describe what you're after in better detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, a `2nd` theorem environment which 'depends' on the `upper` level environment `theo` is a cleaner solution than to use `\begingroup...\endgroup` etc. and storing the counter, changing the output etc.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[chapter]

\newtheorem{subtheo}{Subheorem}[theo] % Use theo as driver counter
\renewcommand{\thesubtheo}{\thetheo\Alph{subtheo}} % Change subtheo counter for alpha output


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\begin{theo}
test
\end{theo}

\begin{subtheo}
test
\end{subtheo}


\end{document}
```

[image]