# Referencing labels created for theorems inside a subtheorem environment links to the theorem before

Tags: numbering, theorems

I am currently trying to create subtheorems that are linkable. I referenced the code put forth by another post, here: [How do I get sub-numbering for theorems (Theorem 1.A., Theorem 1.B., Theorem 2.)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43346/how-do-i-get-sub-numbering-for-theorems-theorem-1-a-theorem-1-b-theorem-2/43351#43351)

I have tried to adapt it to numbering using the following code but it seemst o link to a theorem before the one inside the subtheorem environment. I am wondering if there is perhaps a fix to this. For example, running the code below and linking to Theorem 2A leads to Theorem 1 instead. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linktoc=page,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subtheorem}[1]{%
  \def\subtheoremcounter{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\theparentnumber{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \setcounter{parentnumber}{\value{#1}}%
  \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{\theparentnumber.\Alph{#1}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{\subtheoremcounter}{\value{parentnumber}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
\newcounter{parentnumber}

% - - environments
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}


\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:one}
One
\end{thm}

\begin{subtheorem}{thm}\label{thm:two}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:twoA}
Two, first part
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:twoB}
Two, second part
\end{thm}
\end{subtheorem}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:three}
Three
\end{thm}

\ref{thm:one}, \ref{thm:two}, \ref{thm:twoA}, \ref{thm:twoB}, \ref{thm:three}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You should load `hyperef` as the *last* package
2. The code you are using is a modification of the `subequations` code from `amsmath.sty`, so you also need a mimic the code `hyperef` has specific to `subequations`

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[linktoc=page,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\newcounter{parentnumber}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{subtheorem}[1]{%
  \def\subtheoremcounter{#1}%
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \protected@edef\theparentnumber{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
  \protected@edef\theHparentnumber{\@ifundefined{theH#1}%
  \csname the#1\endcsname\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
  \setcounter{parentnumber}{\value{#1}}%
  \setcounter{#1}{0}%
  \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{\theparentnumber.\Alph{#1}}%
  \expandafter\def\csname theH#1\endcsname{\theparentnumber.\Alph{#1}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{\subtheoremcounter}{\value{parentnumber}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:one}
One
\end{thm}

Text

text

text

\begin{subtheorem}{thm}\label{thm:two}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:twoA}
Two, first part
\end{thm}

Text

text

text

\begin{thm}\label{thm:twoB}
Two, second part
\end{thm}
\end{subtheorem}

Text

text

text

\begin{thm}\label{thm:three}
Three
\end{thm}

\ref{thm:one}, \ref{thm:two}, \ref{thm:twoA}, \ref{thm:twoB}, \ref{thm:three}.

\end{document}
```

Here is what is written it the `.aux` file

```
\newlabel{thm:one}{{1}{1}{}{thm.1}{}}
\newlabel{thm:two}{{2}{1}{}{thm.2}{}}
\newlabel{thm:twoA}{{2.A}{1}{}{thm.2.A}{}}
\newlabel{thm:twoB}{{2.B}{1}{}{thm.2.B}{}}
\newlabel{thm:three}{{3}{1}{}{thm.3}{}}
```

which shows that the extra hyperref arguments are correctly set matching the counters.  Your original code generated

```
\newlabel{thm:twoA}{{2.A}{1}{}{thm.1}{}}
```

which was not what you wanted.

The position of the links for `thm:twoA` and `thm:twoB` are now fine.  However, note that `thm:two` points to where `subtheorem` is issued.  The subsequent `\begin{thm}` adds some vertical space, so the `thm:two` link is not on the line of the heading of the theorem.  There is really no way around this with your current set-up.

Comment: Thank you, very great explanation I was scratching my head for hours over!